# How should I do 3D games through Java on a mac?

Tags: opengl, java, jogl

I have been self-teaching myself Java on the mac mostly because the language is cross-platform. Recently, I have been only able to develop 2D games using the Graphics2D class. 
Now, I want to learn how to make 3D games in Java. I used to model and animate stuff in 3D, so my knowledge of 3-Dimensional stuff is okay.

I have spent the last 3 hours using google to look up ways of making 3D games in java. Apparently the best one to use is OpenGL, so i looked up a tutorial on it and i cannot find a tutorial that shows how to (if there is a way) install JOGL on the Mac platform.

Should i continue to use Java?

How can i make 3D games using Java?

What is the best way to make 3D games on a mac?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend using [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/). It's an OpenGL library for Java that works on Mac, Linux, and Windows.

You can make 3D games in Java just as easily as you would in C or C++ using LWJGL. Although some may complain that Java is slow, modern Java is fast enough for game purposes.

An example of a successful game created using LWJGL: [Minecraft](http://minecraft.net). Another: Revenge of the Titans (cannot post link.)

If you're looking for more game-development tutorials, there are many available on the LWJGL wiki / website / forums. Also, you can follow many C or C++ OpenGL tutorials as the OpenGL functions work almost exactly the same on Java.

Comment: Thank you, do you know of any good tutorials i could use?

Comment: LWJGL is not a good place to start for the beginners.

Comment: ...unless of course s/he has previous experience with OpenGL.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to go for [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) with my eyes closed. Its based on LWJGL. But, starting form pure LWJGL can be quite a lengthy road. jMonkey engine is based on LWJGL and all the necessary things are already done for you. You just need to have a game concept and jump right into programming, which is very easy with jME. As you have mentioned your skill level as beginner in your post, I would suggest not-to-start with LWJGL.

Its on Beta right now. But, don't back of. Its quite stable and full of feature. Most importantly its a shader based engine. There are some fixed function rendering pipeline support, but hey, who should pick an old tech unless s/he has a very specific reason to do so?

Documentations are absolutely fantastic. Very rich and covering a wider variety of concepts. Anyone with a basic java skill can jump right in. Community forum is vibrant. If you stumble upon any bug, its fixed very quickly.

jME isn't just a java library. It comes with a game development environment which is based on NetBeans. All 3rd party tools like, Font Converter, Blender/mesh/obj importer, Scene Editor all are included, they just work!

I can't emphasis it enough. There are lots of other java based game engine out there. But trust me your time with jME, you wont regret it.

oh, did I mention...jME has just announced a Game contest as its stable release is nearing. join it if you can. :)

If you still wish to know about other java engines, just give a knock.