# Game Programming in java

Tags: java

I'm new to this site as well as new in game development, so I need to get a great start for it. Can anybody tell me from where I should start and some books or link are appreciable.
What are the prerequisites to start game programming in java?
I already knows the concepts of `java`.

Comment: Read my answer in this question : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19596/how-should-i-do-3d-games-through-java-on-a-mac/19604#19604

Comment: And read this one too : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15782/can-you-help-me-find-resources-for-developing-a-top-down-2d-game-in-java/15784#15784

Comment: And if you wonder what might be the end result of using Java for game development : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/famous-games-written-in-java

Comment: I have 3 words: don't do it.

Comment: @bobobobo is it because gaming industry is/will be dominated by C & C++ for the foreseeable future, that' why?

Comment: @iamcreasy Java, like any other interpreted language, is very resource intensive. No matter how well you write your code you will always have to surrender some of the systems resources for the virtual machine that java will run within.

Comment: @James Calling Java interpreted implies a lot of things it isn't.  Java is bytecode-compiled, and the JVM is free to do just-in-time compiling to the native language at runtime.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326071/is-java-a-compiled-or-an-interpreted-programming-language

Comment: Also, calling java "slow" is a relative term.  Sure, for CPU-heavy stuff, certain tests will show java as taking ~twice as long (example test: http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64/performance.php?test=mandelbrot&sort=fullcpu), but there's a lot of game code that isn't performance critical.  There are a lot of games that use Lua, which is even slower.  Managed languages have a lot of nice things that can make development a lot faster/easier, and there isn't anything wrong with that.

Comment: @James and in fact java *was slow* but not *is slow.*

Comment: @Tetrad Please do not put words into my mouth, I did not call Java slow. Likewise comparing a programming language to a scripting language does disservice to both regardless of them both being 'interpreted' languages. I was simply attempting to give an answer to a question raised by a very non-constructive comment by bobobobo. This topic should not allowed to be degraded into a Pro vs Anti Java discussion as that is not the OP's question and has been covered more then enough on this site as is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look around at [javagaming](http://www.java-gaming.org/).

Answer (score 6):

Among all java game engines out there, [jMonkeyEngine](http://www.jmonkeyengine.org) is a very good one.

Its just not a library, its comes with a full featured sdk. There is abundance of tutorial and the community is very active. You can check this out too, [jMonkeyEngine Beginner’s Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/jmonkeyengine-3-0-with-java-programming-beginners-guide/book)

Comment: thnx... This info and answer is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at some samples in this repository:

https://github.com/adamgit

https://github.com/adamgit/Entity-System-RDBMS-Beta--Java-

https://github.com/adamgit/Game--Escape-from-the-Pit

It is good introduction into basics of modern game engine architecture in Java (component-based entity systems).

Basic idea is that component-based approach is more suited for games than traditional entity-centric object-oriented. This is because the latter leads to bloated super-classes with lots of responsibilities and rigid inheritance hierarchies.

Comment: Also for a variant, http://www.gamadu.com/artemis/

Comment: You might want to add some description about the contents of your the links. :)