# Wanting to make a quick java game

Tags: java

Hey guys I have experimented in making games in java.  So far I have created A text game in JOptionPane that is kind of like Zork but with yes and no buttons (that were changed to "left" and "right").  I have also made a small game  where a ball bounces around a screen but with was with heavy help from a website tutorial.  Do you guys have any advice or stories about your first game programming? I really want to get into it but it seems like such a steep learning curve.  Any help on where I should start or advice? Thanks guys!

Comment: StackExchange sites aren't really about stories or advice.  They're about getting answers to specific problems you face.  I'll direct you to our faq: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask  If you have a specific question you have, feel free to bring it up in the future.  In the mean time, consider reading through some of these answers: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-are-some-good-resources-for-getting-a-beginner-started-in-developing-games

Answer (score 1):

a quick search will give you lots of results. 
Check this question out: [Game Programming in java](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20414/game-programming-in-java)

Two great game engines you can tinker around with seem to be:

[JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/)

[Lightweight Java Game Library](http://lwjgl.org/)

Good luck :)